# How to clear read only attributes to Kali Linux install partition

Tags: windows-10, kali-linux, read-only

I'm trying to add **Wright** attributes to files in my Kali Linux partition from my Windows 10 partition using **diskpart** `attributes disk clear readonly`.

However,

> DISKPART> select disk 0
>   DISKPART> list partition

shows all partitions except my Kali Linux install partition, so I'm unable to select the partition.

How can I go about calling `attributes disk clear readonly` so that I can be able to delete, edit, move files on my Kali Linux installation directory.

Answer (score 1):

Windows doesn't recognize the Linux partition most likely because it does not understand the File system used on it (the method of organizing raw data on the hard disk).

If you don't know on which file system have you installed Kali, then it's most likely the default - Ext4. As far as i know there are no Ext4 drivers for Windows that support writing into files.

You can deal with this in one of the following ways:

- Gain write access from Kali Linux. Simply login as `root` user and run the following command:

> mount -o remount,rw /

If you have `sudo` available, you can use it to gain `root` user privileges from normal account. To make this permanent you have to open `/etc/fstab` file and replace the `ro` flag with `rw`. Consult the help command `man fstab` for more information and syntax.

- Reinstall Kali Linux onto a File system type which Windows will understand. Examples are FAT32 ( for small partitions ), NTFS, ex-FAT...